# When removing images the last image removed stays (no re-render)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects, each has a URL that is being loaded in this file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :key="id" :src="img" alt="" class="image box" @click="cardClicked" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: ["id", "value", "type", "owner", "imgURL"],
  data() {
    return {
      img: require(`./../assets/${this.imgURL}.png`)
    };
  },
  methods: {
    cardClicked() {
      this.$store.commit("addCardToPlayer", {
        id: this.id,
        type: this.type,
        value: this.value,
        owner: this.owner
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In the Store mutation I preform filtering **and** while filtering I add the card to a another player, like so:

```
 addCardToPlayer(state, clickedCard) {
      const owner = clickedCard.owner;
      const type = clickedCard.type;
      const currPlayer = state.currentPlayerName;
      if (clickedCard.owner === "deck") {
        state.cardOwners[owner].cards[type] = state.cardOwners[owner].cards[
          type
        ].filter(card => {
          if (card.id === clickedCard.id) {
            state.cardOwners[currPlayer].cards[type].push(card);
            return false;
          } else return true;
        });
      }
    },
```

When clicking a card to remove, I see the card being added to the player and displayed correctly, and the number of cards displayed after removal is correct.

**But**

The card that was removed still shows.

What have I tried:

- Forcing to re-render using:

  `cardClicked() {
    this.$store.commit("addCardToPlayer", {
      id: this.id,
      type: this.type,
      value: this.value,
      owner: this.owner
    });
    this.$forceUpdate();
  }`
- Making different components have key, and trying to change the key to cause a re-render:

  `data() {
      return {
        componentKey: 0,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      forceRerender() {
        this.componentKey += 1;

      }
    }`
- Tried changing how I change the array by creating a new state.
- EDIT: Tried using computed. i get an error:

  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'imgURL' of undefined`

  ```
  computed: {
  getImg: () => {
    return require(`./../assets/${this.imgURL}.png`);
  }}
  ```

EDIT: I wrote the computed function as arrow function, which doesn't preserve context.

SOLVED, by using

```
     computed: {
    getImg() {
      return require(`./../assets/${this.imgURL}.png`);
    }}
```

How can I make the images update after click (remove).

Thanks.

Comment: When you click at a card, it should be added to another player (as I understand it happens) and removed from the player who clicked? I think the problem is that you are mutating the state of the store but it's not being reflected in the component because you registered the `img` prop as a data() property, and it should be a computed property. Try it that way

Comment: @LautaroRamos, I tried that but i'm getting property imgURL undefined.
maybe i'm using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, by using

```
 computed: {
getImg() {
  return require(`./../assets/${this.imgURL}.png`);
}}
```